# How can i fix svg image upload error in wordpress?

Tags: image, svg

How to Fix the “Sorry, this file is not permitted for security reasons” WordPress Error

define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);

Comment: There are plugins that can do the job painlessly. Take a look at [Lord of the Files](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/blob-mimes/) and [SVG Support](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/), for example. But first make sure you undrstand the [risks associated with SVG uploads](https://kentwynn.com/wordpress/how-to-safely-upload-svg-files-to-wordpress/kentwynn/31/08/2021/).

Answer (score 0):

**# How to fix ( Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type ) Error**

**# // SVG File Uploads Code**

### Site Tools > Site > File Manager >

**## or goto c-panel and file manager then =**

**## public_html/wp-includes/functions.php**

#### Then past this code and save

```
function add_file_types_to_uploads($file_types){
    $new_filetypes = array();
    $new_filetypes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $file_types = array_merge($file_types, $new_filetypes );
    return $file_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_file_types_to_uploads');
```